# ExtJs and click event on child elements

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have next ExtJs code

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo:'center_div',
    width: 700,    
    layout: 'fit',
    id: 'test',
    items:
    [
        { 
            xtype: 'box', 
            html: '<div style=\"height: 20px;\"> </div>' 
        },
        {         
            xtype: 'box',
            html: '<ul> ' + 
                    '<li id="id1" class=\"active\"><div>Create</div><span><i></i>Step 1</span></li>' +  
                    '<li id="id2"><div>Assign</div><span><i></i>Step 2</span></li>' + 
                    '<li id="id3"><div>Filter</div><span><i></i>Step 3</span></li>' +
                    '<li id="id4"><div>Summary</div></li>' +
                  '</ul>',
            cls: 'x-wizard-steps',
           // delegate: '.x-wizard-steps > ul',
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function(component) {
                    console.log('component' ,component);                    
                    var childLi = Ext.select('.x-wizard-steps > ul > li'); 
                    console.log('childLi', childLi);
                    console.log('childLi.elements', childLi.elements[0].id);                        
                    Ext.each(childLi.elements, function(item,i) {                        
                        console.log('item', item.id);
                        item = Ext.get(item.id);
                        item.on({
                            click: function(cmp, a) {
                               console.log(cmp);                                
                               console.log(a);
                            }
                        });                    

                    });                             

                   var options = {
                        xtype: 'box',       
                        id: 'comp_',
                        html: 'fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsf',
                        margin: '0 0 8 0'
                   };

                   var component1 = Ext.create('Ext.Component', options);
                   Ext.getCmp('test').add(component1);

                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

I need to put event listener on all **LI** in my box html code.

```
<li id="id2">
   <div>Assign</div><span><i></i>Step 2</span>
</li>
```

Click event works fine but if I click it gives me DIV or SPAN and sometimes LI, depends on where I clicked. How do I always get LI element, no matter which area I clicked in LI??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it

in  here

```
   item.on({
       click: function(cmp, a) {
           console.log(cmp);                                
           console.log(a);
           console.log(this); // My LI
       }
     });
```

**this** has my LI

Comment: Thanks for reporting back after you found the answer.

If this worked out accept this answer so that it helps who is having same problem and even this question will be moved to answered list.